# How can I create an html/javascript file to play swf file of my choice?

Tags: javascript, html, flash

OK, so here's the rub. I downloaded a ton of SWF games online, and I want to create my own way to use them. I want to create a directory in the main menu of my HTML file that brings me to another menu with a ton of different choices of games. I know how to play them using the embed tag, but I don't want to create 40 different HTML files for each different game. I know there's a way to click any game you want and go to one HTML page, remembering which game you clicked, and play it, I just don't know what it is. I want every game to point to one embed.html page and it play the SWF file that you clicked. Any help would be much appreciated. I'm working on a work-around to play games on our crappy school Chromebooks. I might be overlooking something really simple, but I don't care. This would be amazing to have. Thanks StackOverflow!

Comment: Could you provide some code: showing how you plan to embed the games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Changing `SRC` of `<embed>` to change file being shown

Here is something you can try. You can have a button for each game, name the button to the game. Then you can have an `<embed>` item with the `src` set to a default item. Then using the following JS: `document.getElementById("game").src = "game.swf"` to change the `src` of the item to whichever game you would like. Here is an example site I created with two random `.swf` files I downloaded off the the internet. There is a `.swf` file and when you click the button the `.swf` file is changed to a different file:

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
    <button onclick="changeGame()">Click to change</button>
    <embed id="game" src="BannerSnack-ad-336x280.swf" type="">
    <script>
        function changeGame() {
            document.getElementById("game").src = "Car-speakers-590x90.swf"
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

You can create a function for each button and game you want to use, this should be the simplest way to do this as I assume you are new to JS. This allows you to have one page with a number of buttons and one `<embed>` tag to hold the game.

> ## Edit

For your problem it looks like using something like this might help:

```
<button onclick="clicked()">click</button>

<script>
    function clicked() {
        var opened = window.open("");
        opened.document.write("<html><head><title>Game</title></head><body><embed id=\"game\" src=\"game.swf\" type=\"\"></body></html>");
    }
</script>
```

This basically uses JS to create a new web page with an embed section. You can create a new function for each game like above. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Is there a way to open a new page with this information stored or will I have to keep it on the page with the buttons?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I don't think that this method would work with the way I'm trying to do it. I want to click a game button, use the javascript function to change the source, and open a new page, displaying that game. Could I maybe use cookies?

Comment: Yes it was a typo, i was looking into it and then accidentally pressed enter before finishing my comment haha,  will edit my answer with a solution in a second

Comment: Lol that's fine. Did you have an idea though?

Comment: refer to my above comment

Comment: Ah yes. Sometimes I'm a bit blind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207632/discussion-between-alex-hawking-and-harrison-reeves).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you could either make a new tab with a variable linked to the game you click on or [use something like this as a template.](https://github.com/ForgivenNin/retrieve.js) It uses JSON object data to load content onto an HTML doc. You can do that with links to each of your games!